# Google Calendar: How to set up event on the week of a specific day

Tags: google-calendar

I want to set up a Google Calendar event, that lasts on the week of 1st of September. So this year, it would be from 30th August - 5th September, but of course, it would change every year, because every year 1st of September falls on different weeks of the year.

Also, I want to receive notifications on my phone every morning say at 7:00.

How can I achieve this? Could someone please help me with a step-by-step instruction list? :)

Thank you for your help.